# Java JSONObject from JSONArray gets error

Tags: java

I have a simple Json string as a JSONArray like this:

```
[{"id_group":"19","state_active":"1","title":"hello world","token":"55811d9184921469"}]
```

I'm trying to get `title` object with this code:

```
JSONObject title =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("title");
```

To update that with other value of title key by:

```
title.put("title","sample updated string");
```

I get this error:

```
title of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

For this line

```
JSONObject title =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("title");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONObject contains `key` and `value`. In your case `title` is key in `JSONObject`. Do something like this...

```
JSONObject title =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
title.put("title","sample updated string");
```

Answer (score 0):

title is not a `JSON Object` it's a `key` in `key-Value pair` so you can not fetch it by using

```
getJSONObject("title");
```

Instead you should do something like this

```
JSONObject outerJson=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String title =outerJson.getString("title"); //Existing title Value
//Now Modifying title 
title="New Title";
outerJson.put("title",title);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your error claims for itself: title is **String**, not JSONObject